# Separate by line in jquery and post

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Html:
<textarea id="game" type="text" class="resizedTextbox"/></textarea>
<input id="times" type="text" class="resizedTextbox" value=1>
<textarea id="info" type="text" class="resizedTextbox"/></textarea>

JS:
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#game').change(UpdateInfo);
    $('#times').change(UpdateInfo);
});

   function UpdateInfo()
   {
          var times = $('#times').val();
         var game = 
             $('#game').val();
     var line = 'Play ' + game + " " + times
     var info ="Games \n" + line;
     $('#info').val(info);
   }
```

I've also provided a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfzr8/) of the above code.

Now i am stuck at here:

When i type this in text box 1:

```
1Text
2Text
```

i want it to appear as this in text box 2

```
Games 
Play 1text 1
Play 2text 1
```

Now,how can i do it?

Comment: Please also post your code here, if jsfiddle is inaccessible in the future this question would become useless in helping others. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: What Seer says is correct, though with jsFiddle it's more a case of "when" rather than "if" - it's been down for me at least twice in the past week.

Comment: Done....Now i hope i get some answers

Comment: Am I seeing things or these two answers are actually same?

Comment: yep :p....thats what i am seeing too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the lines using the `\n` character. For example you could run:

```
$(this).val().split("\n");
```

So your code will look like this:

```
function UpdateInfo()
{
    var times = $('#times').val(),
        games = $('#game').val().split("\n"),
       output = "Games\n";

    for(var i = 0; i < games.length; i++)
    {
         output += "Play "+games[i]+" "+times+"\n";   
    }

     $('#info').val(output);
}
```

Here's a working [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfzr8/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to split value by lines. Then generate result for each line.

```
function UpdateInfo()
   {
       var times = $('#times').val();
       var game = $('#game').val().split("\n");
       var info = 'Games \n';
       for (var i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
           info += 'Play ' + game[i] + " " + times + "\n"
       }
       $('#info').val(info);
   }
```